# Bose USB speakers fail to load driver

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I've followed several guides to get my speakers working. Primarily the need to modify /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf for the proper index.

The speakers were working with my current config.  However, they recently have started to fail to load the driver at boot.  Here's what I see in dmesg:

```
[   47.721202] usb 1-14: New USB device found, idVendor=05a7, idProduct=1020
[   47.721204] usb 1-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   47.721205] usb 1-14: Product: Bose USB Audio
[   47.721205] usb 1-14: Manufacturer: Bose Corporation
[   47.728551] hid-generic 0003:05A7:1020.0006: hiddev0,hidraw5: USB HID v1.10 Device [Bose Corporation Bose USB Audio] on usb-0000:00:14.0-14/input2
[   47.739669] snd-usb-audio 1-14:1.0: cannot find the slot for index 0 (range 0-0), error: -16
[   47.741328] usb 1-14: cannot create card instance 0
[   47.742215] snd-usb-audio: probe of 1-14:1.0 failed with error -16
```

If I "cat /proc/asound/cards" I only see my HDA Nvidia available.
Same with "lspci | grep -i audio".

```
wrathwolf@wolfnix:~$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfb080000 irq 59
wrathwolf@wolfnix:~$ lspci |grep -i audio
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fb0 (rev a1)
wrathwolf@wolfnix:~$
```

lsmod shows the USB driver is loaded.

```
wrathwolf@wolfnix:~$ lsmod |grep usb
usbserial              49152  1 pl2303
btusb                  32768  0 
bluetooth             491520  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_usb_audio         180224  0 
snd_usbmidi_lib        32768  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hwdep              20480  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  6 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_rawmidi            32768  2 snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_midi
snd                    90112  18 snd_usb_audio,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  2 hid_generic,usbhid
wrathwolf@wolfnix:~$
```

My alsa-base.conf shouldn't have anything to do with this since the system doesn't even detect the speakers anymore. Havning said that, here is a copy of my alsa-base.conf that **was working**.

```
wrathwolf@wolfnix:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf # autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }

# Assign USB Audio as default sound card
options snd_usb_audio index=0

# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
wrathwolf@wolfnix:~$
```

I know it's probably sacrilege to mention it here... But in the name of science, I tested them in Windows 10 (Not VM, dual boot) and they appear to be working there.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's something wrong with the config file, which you haven't shown.

Comment: @CL. I've added my alsa config, but that shouldn't make a difference.  The system fails to even load the device on the bus, therefore the alsa config is never used.  I haven't changed the alsa config since the speakers were working.

Comment: No it's not sacrilege. We use Linux because we like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```perl
options snd_usb_audio index=0
```

This options tells the `snd-usb-audio` driver that when it loads, it must claim the first sound card index.
However, If that sound card index is already used by some other driver (`snd-hda-intel` in your case), loading fails.

In theory, you would need to prevent such conflicts by telling *all* drivers which index to use.
But a better solution is to not use any `index` options, and to specify for each index which driver can claim it:

```perl
options snd slots=snd-usb-audio,snd-hda-intel   # second one not actually needed
```